# scala use a method against a table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, methods, dataset

I have a table `test` with two columns `a: String` and `b: String`. I'm trying to apply some functions to the values in a, say if a = 23 and a-b<5 (real logic might be more complicated than this), then create another table with column c as "yes".

I tried to create a case class `num` as below, convert table to the class `night`, and apply that function to the table. How should I do this, or is this doable? Many thanks!

```
  case class num (a:String, b:String){

          def howmany ={
             // how should I put the logics here?    
           }  
    }

sqlContext.table("test").as[num].//how can I then apply function `howmany`here?
```

Comment: i don't know scala, but there is probably something like a map() function that might be applicable to this situation

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a DataFrame of "num", you can put your logic in an UDF and use DataFrame's withColumn API to call your UDF and add the new column. You can find more details of this method [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need.

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("ParquetAppendMode")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

   val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
     ("123", "125"),
     ("23", "25"),
     ("5", "9")
   )).toDF("a", "b") // create a dataframe with dummy data

  val logic = udf((a: String, b: String) => {
    if (a.toInt ==23 && (a.toInt - b.toInt) <5 ) "yes" else "no"
  })

  // add column with applying logic 
  val result = data.withColumn("newCol", logic(data("a"), data("b")))

  result.show()
```

Comment: you don't need an udf for this, we can use native Spark functions.

Comment: @mtoto I used UDF since he said there is more complex logic in realtime.

Comment: Is `.withColumn` the best way to transform a dataset? I mean what if there are many Columns that I want to append?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dataset's `map`:

```
sqlContext.table("test").as[num]
          .map(num => if(a == 23 && a-b < 5) (num, "yes") else (num, "no"))
```

Or you could just use a filter followed by a select:

```
sqlContext.table("test").where($"a" == 23 && ($"a"-$"b") < 5).select($"*", "yes".as("newCol"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it's achieveable with `.withColumn`.I'm just wondering if there are other ways of doing it. I have many columns that I want to append, and multiple conditions so there will me many `where`as well.

Comment: Another problem is, that a, b, might be columns

Comment: You need to provide specifics, as this should handle those scenarios afaik. Maybe you're talking about you need a case statement?